# After hooking up a USB outlet, some of my outlets and switches stopped working

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have recently change my electrical outlets from the standard one to one with a USB port. That outlet is controlled by a light switch. After installing I check to see if there’s power at the outlet and it was live. After check the outlet if functioning properly I realize the light switch stop working and a portion of the house (closet and half of the bedroom outlets) stop having power. Does anyone know what could be wrong I have triple check my work and all the wires are connected properly. Can the switch is stopping the circuit ?

Comment: Can you post pictures of the switch & outlet boxes showing all the wires?

Comment: Please look at the old receptacle and tell us if any of the **tabs** are broken off.

Comment: If you can, post pictures of both the old and new receptacles....

Comment: I tested the wires I’m getting zero volt at the switch

Comment: Is it possible it was mis-wired and tripped a breaker or GFCI?  Is it does turn out to be this,  dont keep resetting it,  find the fault in your new outlet with it off.

Answer (score 0):

When you loose a portion of a circuit it is a bad connection, wire nuts look like they are connected but 1 wire is not in a bundle or you used back stabs and the back stab failed (I have seen this hundreds of times if not thousand times over the years). So your light switch is not working now that controlled the outlet this is a clue, did you take a photo of the wiring prior to pulling the old outlet? A switch loop may have white going to black and depending on how you wired things up it may have caused problems if not a bad connection. We would need a photo of the switch wiring and the outlet to provide a more complete solution but if you changed wire for wire on the new outlet look for a loose connection.

Comment: I took some pics trying to figure out how to upload them